# Make child container fixed relatively to parent div(with non-fixed height)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

By default, when user opens my page he can see only "**imagecontainer**" div with images and "**imagebutton**" has status "*selected*".

When user clicks on "**Videos**" button, I make "**Videos**" button selected,
hide "**imagecontainer**" and show "**videocontainer**".

The problem is, that my “**maincontainer**” height is not fixed. When user switches from videos to images, back and force, and since images and videos are sometimes *different in sizes*, my “**button-row**” shifts also up and down. Making experience inconsistent.

I am not allowed to change "**maincontainer**" width , change it's properties or position or add something to this layout. *I can only change* "**videocontainer**" or “**button-row**”.

I tried to make my "**button-row**" with absolute position and give to it "*bottom:0*" to stick it to the bottom of parent container. However it didn't worked.

Is there any workarounds? Can I do it through jquery? Somehow capture initial height of **maincontainer**. And then, if user clicks Videos button, force **maincontainer** to have the same height that I captured on initial page load (when Image button is selected)

```
<div id=“maincontainer”>
    <div>Some data</div>
    <div id = "imagecontainer"> My image is here</div>
    <div id = "videocontainer"> My video is here</div>
    <div id = “button-row”>
        <button id=“imagebutton” class="selected" type="button">Image</button> 
        <button id=“videobutton” type="button">Video</button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Css for main container:

```
#maincontainer{
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work (untested)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($("#imagecontainer").height() > $("#videocontainer").height()) {
        $("#videocontainer").height($("#imagecontainer").height());
    } else {
        $("#imagecontainer").height($("#videocontainer").height());
    }
});
```